# Can't tell when Jasmine is done running

Tags: jasmine, gulp

I have the following Gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
  livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
  sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
  jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine'),
  app = require('./app'),
  server = require('http').createServer(app);

gulp.task('test', function () {
  return server.listen(3000, function() {
    gulp.src('spec/test.js')
      .pipe(jasmine());
  });
});
```

When the tests are done running I'd like to do a `server.close()` to kill the server. (Otherwise the command just hangs.)

But I don't know how to tell when the tests are done running. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. The significant difference is the `on` callback, I suppose.

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  server.listen(3000);
  return gulp.src('spec/test.js')
    .pipe(jasmine())
    .on('end', function () {
      server.close();
    });
});
```